# Disable default Expo splash screen

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I want to disable the default Expo splash screen and show my custom screen component. I've removed the following code from `app.json` but still there is a white blank loading before my custom screen.

```
 "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
        ...,
      },
```

I've read information in Google, in the duplicated topics and also in the documentation here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/ but I don't understand clearly. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but you can make default splash and your custom splash same.

Answer (score 0):

For me a combination of three things:

1. Removing the expo-splash-screen section from my **app.json**
2. Editing my **Podfile** to specifically exclude expo-splash-screen from being installed (see below)

   use_expo_modules!(exclude: ['expo-splash-screen'])
3. Adding a new splashscreen using **XCode** (see link below)
4. Clearing all caches (Pods, Podfile,lock, Node Mods & Yarn.lock) and rebuilding.

Hope this helps.

[React Native IOS Splash Screen With Storyboard](https://echobind.com/post/react-native-ios-splash-screen-with-storyboard)

Answer (score -2):

Read this :
[Configuring a splash screen and app icon](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/configuration/) and
[Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/splash-screens/)
or use `expo install expo-splash-screen` [Doc SplashScreen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)

Comment: The question talks about how to disable the splash screen, not how to create one. The information you provide is about how to create a splash screen and I already know how to do that. This is not the question to the answer.  I already read all the information you refer to before I post the question here.